# Can I remove a repeated word in this sentence?

Tags: ellipsis, parallelism

I have a sentence, say:

> He has worked in banking industry and manufacturing industry for more than 15 years.

My question is the first "industry" could be omitted? If done, we should use "banking and manufacturing industry" or "banking and manufacturing industries"? Which one is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can remove the redundant "industry", but both banking and manufacturing together are two *industries*, plural.  Don't forget the definite article:

> He has worked in **the** banking and manufacturing **industries** for more than 15 years.

However, in this context "industry" itself is not necessary.  By definition, things like "banking" or "manufacturing" or "commerce" or "trade" or "shipping" represent categories of *industries*.  Since these are generic concepts, don't use the definite article:

> He has worked in banking and manufacturing for more than 15 years.